# Circuit with a MCP9700 temp sensor - What this capacitor is used for?

Tags: capacitor

I have built a circuit that uses a MCP9700 to read the temperature as explained [here](http://startingelectronics.com/beginners/start-electronics-now/tut15-arduino-serial-thermometer/).

This is the circuit schema:

[image: circuit schema]

I understand that C2 is used as a decoupling capacitor to clean up the noise ([datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/21942a.pdf)). However, I am not sure about C1. Is it a decoupling capacitor as well? I did the experiment without C1 and the temperature reading was not significantly affected.

Comment: C1 could help the ADC inside the arduino produce a more stable reading.

Comment: OK, so how can I be sure that it is  it's purpose? And how would you calculate the actual value? I saw this diagram in a couple of tutorials but nobody ever explained what's C1 purpose.

Comment: According to the datasheet, no additional parts are needed. C1 was added in for who knows what reason. Microchip doesn't recommend it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is on the datasheet 1st page:

[image]

So in short it doesn't hurt and slows down the response to prevent overshoot, presumably upon power up or from Power supply ripples.  The PSR is \$0.1 ^\circ C/V\$ which is not bad.

Comment: Arf, I did not read carefully enough the datasheet and I missed this information.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of C1 is just to remove off the fluctuations in the analog output given by the sensor. It is basically acting as a noise filter making the output more and more stable even in the noisy environment.